# Android Studio: Multiple Textviews in ExpandableListView and set value

Tags: android, arraylist

I am new in Android studio, I am trying to add value to my 4 text View that are in my Expandable List View. I do believe I am not missing a lot of coding because when I add `resto.add("something");`. This is copying my value 4 times.

In my Adapter.java:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);
    }

TextView address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.address);
TextView phone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
TextView lunchTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lunchTime);
TextView lunchDetails = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lunchDetails);

String text = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

address.setText(text);
lunchTime.setText(text);
lunchDetails.setText(text);

return convertView;
}
```

and in my mainActiviity.java:

```
private void init() {
    groupList = new ArrayList<String>();
    childMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    List<String> resto = new ArrayList<String>();
       //Want to set value to address, phone, lunchTime and lunchDetails

    groupList.add("resto");
    childMap.put(groupList.get(0), resto);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: please post all adapter code

Comment: Finalement, I managed to add specific value with this code:         
resto.add(0, "item11");

But now, my value are scooping 4 times (beacause I have 4 index in the ArrayList) How to limit the scoop to one?